# Swift - Different object in console/debugger

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm currently having a big WTF moment and I have no idea what's going on

So I have this little piece of code

```
let par2 = bla.parameter[2]!
print(par2)
```

bla is a object of a class called FITService which is a singleton and parameter is a dictionary with the ID of an object.
The class of the object is called Parameter and looks like this:

```
class Parameter:Object{

    dynamic var parameterID:Int = -1
    dynamic var name:String = ""
    dynamic var updatedAt:Date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)

    convenience init(json:JSON){
        self.init()

        self.parameterID = json["parameterid"].int ?? -1
        self.name = json["name"].string ?? ""
        self.updatedAt = Date.from(mysql: json["updatedAt"].string)
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "parameterID"
    }
}
```

I'm using Realm to save the objects and SwiftyJSON/Alamofire to get data from a backend and convert it.

So to come to the wtf moment: I've set a breakpoint after the print() line from the first snippet and this is the output:
[image]

So in the debugger the object has different values then when printing???
How is this possible?

Comment: I think this is just a bug in debugger, and it's happen with Objective-C, too. File a bug report. ;)

Comment: Agreed. This looks like some kind of error is occurring with the Xcode Realm `Object` introspection. Please file an issue at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues :)

Comment: This is intended behavior. Realm object doesn't use instance variables. For lazy loading, Realm object lazily loads values through custom accessor when property access happens. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1131